# How to mutate points to lines in simple feature collections

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

I have a simple feature data frame with coordinates from the starting point. From this starting point, I need to find *new, unknown, coordinates* which are 1 km north, and 1 km north + 1 km east from the starting point.

I then need to create line segments from first to second point and second to third point.

I would like to do this by mutating the geography column.

Example:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

SF_df <- 
tibble(case = c("A", "B", "C"),
       LAT = 523456, LONG = 652348) %>% 
st_as_sf(coords = c("LONG", "LAT"), crs = "+proj=utm +zone=33    +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

#make new points
SF_df %>% 
mutate(geometry = ifelse(case == "A", geometry, 
                  ifelse(case == "B", geometry+c(0,1000),
                       geometry + c(1000,1000))))
```

I tried

```
 SF_df %>% 
 mutate(geometry = ifelse(case == "A", st_linestring(geometry,    geometry+c(0,1000)),
                ifelse(case == "B", st_linestring(geometry+c(0,1000), geometry+c(1000,1000)), NA)))
```

which doesn't work because `st_linestring`need a matrix of numerical values. I also tried transforming the points with `as.numeric(as.coordinates( x))` which doesn't work either.

The result should be a sf data frame with one line per point + 1 line per linestring between points.

any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to end up with 2 lines?

Comment: yes. The answer by @www is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `group_by`, `summarize`, and `st_cast` to `LINESTRING`. `SF_df3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

SF_df <- 
  tibble(case = c("A", "B", "C"),
         LAT = 523456, LONG = 652348) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("LONG", "LAT"), crs = "+proj=utm +zone=33    +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

#make new points
SF_df2 <- SF_df %>% 
  mutate(geometry = ifelse(case == "A", geometry, 
                           ifelse(case == "B", geometry+c(0,1000),
                                  geometry + c(1000,1000)))) 

# Make a linestring
SF_df3 <- SF_df2 %>%
  mutate(Line = "A") %>%
  group_by(Line) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
```

Or you may want to consider making two linestrings as follows. The key is to create start and end for each linestring (in this case, duplicate the second row) and assign an ID for each linestring, and then follow the same step as the previois solution. `SF_df4` is the final output.

```
# Make two linestring
SF_df4 <- SF_df2 %>%
  # Duplicate the second row
  slice(1, 2, 2, 3) %>%
  mutate(Line = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2)) %>%
  group_by(Line) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
```